# How create dynamic edittext from using api with input validation in android

Tags: android

I need to generate dynamic input fields from API in Android. I also need to add proper input validation submit button like not empty, valid number so on. I have tried to generate the text field below like image:

[image]

My API JSON is below:

```
  fields": [
                {
                    "code": "ACCT_NO",
                    "type": "textbox",
                    "required": true,
                    "default_value": null,
                    "options": null,
                    "regex": "^[0-9]*$",
                    "config": null,
                    "label": "Enter Account No:"
                },
                {
                    "code": "AMNT",
                    "type": "textbox",
                    "required": true,
                    "default_value": null,
                    "options": null,
                    "regex": "^[0-9]*$",
                    "config": null,
                    "label": "Enter Amount:"
                },
                {
                    "code": "ADD_MSISDN",
                    "type": "textbox",
                    "required": false,
                    "default_value": null,
                    "options": null,
                    "regex": null,
                    "config": null,
                    "label": "Additional MSISDN (Optional):"
                }
            ]
```

Here is my XML code named input_field_layout.xml for generate input textfield:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="8dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColorHint="#9E9E9E"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my Activity XML code:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the fields generate code:

```
        fun poplulateFields(fields: List<Field>){
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            for (x in fields) {
                if (x.type.equals("textbox")){
                    val inputFieldLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_field_layout, containerLayout, false)
                    val textInputLayout = inputFieldLayout.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.textInputLayout)
                    val textInputEditText = inputFieldLayout.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.textInputEditText)
                    textInputEditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                    textInputLayout.hint = x.label
                    if(x.required){
                        if(x.regex != null || x.regex !=""){
                            val regexPattern = x.regex
                            textInputEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

                                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

                                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                                    val value = s.toString()
                                    val isValid = value.matches(Regex(regexPattern))
                                    if (isValid) {
                                        // Valid input
                                        textInputLayout.error = null
                                    } else {
                                        // Invalid input
                                        textInputLayout.error = "Invalid input"
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }

                    }
                    containerLayout.addView(inputFieldLayout)
                    // Add the EditText to the list for later use
                    editTextList.add(textInputEditText)
                }

            }
        }
```

Here is my submit button code:

```
        btnNext.setOnClickListener {
                Log.e("btnNext---","btnNext")
                val fieldValues = mutableMapOf<Int, String>()

                for (editText in editTextList) {
                    val value = editText.text.toString()
                    val fieldId = editText.id
                    fieldValues[fieldId] = value

                    Log.e("fieldId-",fieldId.toString())
                    Log.e("value-",value.toString())
                }


            }
```

How to set the id from JSON to textfield which comes from json defined  in "code": "ACCT_NO"?

how to validate input field **not empty or not null or other validation** on submit next button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tag` to store code data

```
val inputFieldLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_field_layout, containerLayout, false)
val textInputLayout = inputFieldLayout.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.textInputLayout)
val textInputEditText = inputFieldLayout.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.textInputEditText)
textInputEditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
textInputEditText.tag = x.code // store code data into edit text
textInputLayout.hint = x.label
```

and retrieve code data from `tag`

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener {
    Log.e("btnNext---","btnNext")
    val fieldValues = mutableMapOf<Int, String>()

    for (editText in editTextList) {
        val value = editText.text.toString()
        val fieldId = editText.tag // get code data
        fieldValues[fieldId] = value

        Log.e("fieldId-",fieldId.toString())
        Log.e("value-",value.toString())
    }
}
```

To validate input fields not empty on clicking the next button, use the validation function and if statement.

```
// validating all fields are not empty
fun checkFieldsNotEmpty(editTextList: List<TextInputEditText>): Boolean {
    for (editText in editTextList) {
        if (editText.text.isNullOrEmpty()) return false
    }

    return true
}

btnNext.setOnClickListener {
    // any edit text is empty then return
    if (!checkFieldsNotEmpty(editTextList)) return@setOnClickListener

    Log.e("btnNext---","btnNext")
    val fieldValues = mutableMapOf<Int, String>()

    for (editText in editTextList) {
        val value = editText.text.toString()
        val fieldId = editText.id
        fieldValues[fieldId] = value

        Log.e("fieldId-",fieldId.toString())
        Log.e("value-",value.toString())
    }
}
```